# Proper usage of next() in Koa.js Middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa, koa2

I use Koa (2.11.0).

I have this very much simplified middleware function, which looks strange after simplification.

However, it is easier to ask the question.
I have two if statements, and I throw three times.
After throwing, I am unsure what would be the best thing to do in all three places:

1. do nothing, Koa will handle all
2. add return, while it makes no value adding it, at least some readability to the code.
3. add return next()

```js
//This is Koa middleware
const tokenProvider: (persons: string[]) => Middleware = (
): Middleware => {
  return async (ctx: Context, next: () => Promise<void>): Promise<void> => {
    const authorizationHeader: string = ctx.headers.authorization

    if (!authorizationHeader) {
      ctx.throw(STATUS_CODES.UNAUTHORIZED)
    }
    try {
      const token: string = authorizationHeader.split(' ').pop()
      if (!token ) {
        ctx.throw(STATUS_CODES.FORBIDDEN)
        // Should I use:
        // - return
        // - return next()
        // - nothing should be used, as Koa will handle it
      }

      return next()
    } catch (error) {
      ctx.throw(STATUS_CODES.UNAUTHORIZED)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Koa's `ctx.throw` actually throws an exception, so there's no point in putting statements immediately after `ctx.throw` as they will be skipped, just as they would with `throw new Error()`.

This also means that this statement isn't useful:

```
ctx.throw(STATUS_CODES.FORBIDDEN)
```

Because you immediately catch it and turn it into something else after. This is how I would rewrite your middleware:

```
//This is Koa middleware
const tokenProvider: (persons: string[]) => Middleware = (
): Middleware => {
  return async (ctx: Context, next: () => Promise<void>): Promise<void> => {

    const authorizationHeader: string = ctx.headers.authorization

    if (!authorizationHeader || !authorizationHeader.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
      ctx.set('WWW-Authenticate: Bearer');
      ctx.throw(
        STATUS_CODES.UNAUTHORIZED,
        'Authentication with a Bearer token is required on this endpoint',
      );
    }
    const token = authorizationHeader.substr('Bearer '.length);
    // I supposed you want check the bearer token here? 
    return next()
  }
}
```

Note that I assume you're using `Bearer` tokens, but if you're using something else you can substitute this.

Comment: That is a very useful piece of information with the catch and error. I completely overlooked it. Thank you, I will keep it in mind.